# How do I use the word "obtain" together with mathematical formulas?

Tags: word-usage, reading

Until now, I thought that one can use the word "obtain" together with "that", as in

> By ... we obtain that a²+b²=c².

(Many mathematicians who like me are not native speakers are doing this!)
Now I found two documents saying that "that" doesn't belong here: [This Polish site](http://www.impan.pl/cgi-bin/dict?obtain), and the [guide of the London Mathematical Society](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Bulletin/writing.pdf) to writing mathematics, which says that "obtain" should usually not be followed by "that".

Now my question: if instead of the above I write

> By ... we obtain a²+b²=c².

how do I *read* that sentence? "We obtain a square plus b square equals c square"? Then it appears that I use "obtain" with the verb "equals", which sounds a bit strange to me.

What would be the correct version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Obtain* cannot take a *that* clause, so *we obtain that* is ungrammatical.

You second example is common in technical papers, and treats the equation as a sort of quotation. What you are saying is something like

> *We obtain "a squared plus b squared equals c squared"*

where the grammar inside the quoted string is irrelevant to the main sentence. (Note that the subscript 2 is read *squared*, not *square*).

You could achieve a similar effect by saying *we obtain **the result** a squared...* or _we obtain **the equation** a squared ... _.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation! (And also thanks for pointing out the "squared".) Just to make sure I got it right: are you saying the version "we obtain a²+b²=c²" is alright for a technical paper and I don't _need_ to add the phrase "the result" or "the equation"?

Comment: In mathematics, physics, and computer science, at least, "we obtain a²+b²=c²" is fine for a technical paper. (I suspect you are putting "that" in by analogy with expressions such as "we find that a²+b²=c².") Mathematics, physics, and computer science treat equations as part of the sentence, and use grammar and punctuation accordingly. Some disciplines didn't use to treat equations this way—I don't know whether this is still the case. If it is, you might have to put a noun such as "the result" before "a²+b²=c²."

Comment: @Peter: Thank you very much! I'm talking about math here, so it appears I'm on the safe side. (By the way, my analogy was "we infer that a²+b²=c²", and I thought I could use "obtain" as somewhat of a synonym.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt Though drawing or deducing an inference from a series of calculations is essentially the same as *getting* a result, the two words *infer* and *get* behave differently. *We infer that ...*, but *We obtain ...* . In case it helps, *obtain* simply means *get*, not *infer*.

Comment: @Kris: Yeah, that helps, thanks. Now I have a German analogy: "get" means "bekommen", and "wir bekommen, dass" is also ungrammatical.

Comment: @HendrikVogt "Von zwei und zwei erhalten wir vier." "From two and two we get four."

Comment: @HendrikVogt: since you are asking about niceties of English, I hope you won't mind my pointing out that _on the safe side_ is an idiom meaning _taking precautions against some undesired outcome_. So in this context we might say _I think that "we obtain a²+b²=c²" is OK, but to be on the safe side I'll say "we obtain the result a²+b²=c²"_. I think _on safe ground_ might be an idiom which matches your intent.

Comment: @Colin: Thank you so much! I'd really like to improve my English, so I appreciate your pointing this out.